# Not able to write to file as Read/write permissions change during deployment

Tags: r, permissions, chmod

I am trying to do a local build for deploying my R script
The R script `writes to a file config.json`

It works fine when I run the code from RStudio.

While creating a local deployment I get the error:`cannot open file 'config.json': Permission denied`, as the user is different when I do a local build

checking the permissions I see that they are `rw-r--r--.`

Is it possible that the local build gets sufficient permissions to write to config.json